# Find the area of a region defined by a complex inequation.

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers, area

I just did a Calculus 1 test and I couldn't solve the first question, which goes as follows:

1. Find the area of the region defined by:

$\left|z + \frac{12}{\bar{z}}\right| ≤ 7$

I tried to use $z= a+bi$ (which ended up costing me 20 min of the exam for nothing), multiplying the conjugate by $z$ to get it out of there, trying to factor out $|z|$ as I saw in a video but nothing.

I would really appreciate any process or hint to solve it,

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

$$z\cdot \bar{z}=|z|^2. $$

$$\left|z+\frac{12}{\bar{z}}\right|\le 7\iff |z|^2+12\le 7|\bar{z}|=7|z|. $$

$\iff |z|\in[3,4]. $That's an annulus.

Comment: Thank you very much, could you elaborate more in the process of getting from the initial expression to |z|2+12≤7|z¯|=7|z|?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach with $z=x+yi$ was indeed correct. We will need several properties, regarding complex conjugate and the absolute value, such as:

1. $|\dfrac{z}{w}| = \dfrac{|z|}{|w|}$,
2. $z\cdot\bar{z}= |z|^2 = x^2+y^2$.

   $|z+\dfrac{12}{\bar{z}}|\le 7 \iff |\dfrac{z\cdot \bar{z}+12}{\bar{z}}|\le 7 \iff\dfrac{|z\cdot \bar{z}+12|}{|\bar{z}|}\le 7$

   $\iff \dfrac{|x^2+y^2+12|}{|x-yi|}\le 7$

   We know that $x^2+y^2+12 > 0$ (a positive real) for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$, so $|x^2+y^2+12|=x^2+y^2+12$. Next, we also know that $|\bar{z}|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2} = |z|$. Hence, we have:
   $$
   x^2+y^2+12 \le 7\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \iff \boxed{|z|^2 + 12 \le 7|z|}.
   $$
   Knowing this, we can easily proceed and conclude:
   $$
   \boxed{3 \le |z| \le 4}.
   $$
   Finding the area of above region is now an easy task!